# Add to home screen is prompt coming even after PWA app installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is there an way to check if the PWA app is already installed?

can prompt event can be cancelled may be in `'beforeinstallprompt'` event

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  // in here        
});
```

**Note:** This specifically happening in oneplus 6T (chrome) and all other phones this works fine

Comment: Has something changed in the manifest?

Comment: They SHOULD not get prompted to get installed if it is already. Are you sure the  user sees the app Icon for your PWA with all other app icons on their device?

Answer (score 0):

If a user is using Google Chrome, the following will be relevant:

**Add to Home Screen**

By Pete LePage

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Quote:

> In order for a user to be able to install your Progressive Web App, it needs to meet the following criteria:
>
> - The web app is not already installed.

Also, when the user has successfully installed the app, there is a callback from the `appinstalled` event.  You can use this to persist the fact that the user has installed the app (perhaps in localStorage or indexedDB):

Quote:

> **Determine if the app was successfully installed**
>
> To determine if the app was successfully added to the user's home screen after they accepted the prompt, you can listen for the `appinstalled` event.
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
>     app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
> });
> ```

Comment: Despite of its name, and despite the content of many articles and blog, "appinstalled" is (unfortunaltly) NOT fired when the app is installed but is fired at the beginning of the installation. It seems there is no event fired when the installation is sucessful.